# java -EWS-api calendar archive

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

1

I am using Pull Notification and EWS to have synchronization of appointments with Exchange 2010 server and my application. It works find, I am able to pull notification whenever user create, modify or delete an appointment.

Users have auto archive in their Microsoft Outlook, the auto archive can delete or move appointments in their calendar in Outlook, and notification fired and Pull Notification gets the message and process accordingly, this is correct.

What I want to ask is, is there a way EWS can check whether the appointment (delete or modify or move) is archive

Thanks.

The following code is how I use EWS Java-API, i think i can get archiveTag from Appointment,but it not work,The APPOINTMENT class has no way to get ArchiveTag

```java
       PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        propertySet.add(AppointmentSchema.Recurrence);
        propertySet.add(AppointmentSchema.ICalUid);
        //there is no archive propertySet with AppointmentSchema
        ExchangeService service2 = getExchangeService("*****", "****");
      
       Appointment appointment2 = Appointment.bind(service2,new ItemId("::"),propertySet);
```